# Get Facebook friends who've installed my app problems

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I just released an iOS app that has Facebook integration, and /me/friends is not working as I expected.  When a new user logs in (or an existing user for that matter) and I use "startWithGraphPath:" to get the users' friends', I only receive people who were friends prior to us deploying the application.  So, the API call works, friends are returned, but not all the friends that I know are using the app.

Does anyone know if there's a significant time lag to this working?

On the app developer page it shows a green light and that the app is available to all users.

On the status page it says user_friends is an available permission.

Why would I get some users, but not all?  I used my wife's phone to sign on to the application, but yet when I ask for friends, she is not returned.

Any insight is appreciated.

Ken

Comment: You also need to ask the user for user_friends permission.

Comment: I am already doing that.  What I have discovered is it seems to be tied to app visibility.  When someone logs onto my app, the app visibility is set to "Only Me".  Why would that be?  I can't find anywhere that says how to change this.